# Page views are not displayed

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-page

Some of the pages in Page Library are not showing number of visits when clicking on ... Could someone please help if this can be sorted out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

page views fetched by Search Service Application!
After next crawl, the page views should be displayed.

this props in search schema are for page views :)

[image]

I've read something about Page Views property and found out, that the usage and health service application is part of it, too...

I cant find the source for that anymore, but I figured out, that page views are not "indexed/recognized" as soon as you visit the page... you have to wait several minutes/hours/days (??)...

Comment: Unfortunately, pages most visited are not displayed with number of views :)